# ChromeDriver throws JVM Bind Exception

Tags: webdriver

im encoutaring some wierd behaviuor with the ChromeDriver on Selenium 2.0.

i have a test suite that consists of about 20 tests.
when i run the test individualy, they all work fine. both on firefox and chrome.

though when i run the entire suite on chrome i get a JVM Bind Exception telling me the address is already in use.
the thing is that the first 2-3 tests pass, and it only happens after them.
maybe OS is having trouble recycling processes?

the suite works perfectly on firefox...

any ideas?

i use window xp 32bit OS.

thanks

Comment: Please correct the spelling from "encoutaring" to "encountering".

Answer (score 1):

try calling "webDriver.quit()" method after the end of each test. Selenium 2 is known to have this bug of exhausting the ephemeral ports, and the above piece of code should get some relief. I tried it, and it does close some ports.

Thanks,
Prakash.